# Move git repository

Tags: git

I have initialized and commited some files within a working directory in the current structure

```
-project_name
--- sofware_directory
----- .git
----- some_directory
-------- working_directory
```

I am realizing i don't need to have the software_directory or some_directory in my repository.
I have not yet pushed this repository. I want the structure to look like this

```
-project_name
--- .git
--- working_directory_B
```

How do I move .git up one level and rearrange the other directories accordingly? I tried to move .git with

```
git mv .git ../
```

but receive the error that '..' is outside repository.

Comment: Where does your git repository start? If the .git is in software_directory, then I'd say that is the starting place. In which case, you can just move everything from software_directory directly into project_name and everything still works. Git uses only paths relative to the project root, so it does not care what the parent directory is. You can't use `git mv`, because that is used for committed files. Just use a regular move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```sh
cd project_name

# These are just file system actions
mv software_directory/* .
mv software_directory/.git .

# This directory needs to be moved by git
git mv some_directory/working_directory/ .
git commit -m 'changed dir layout'

# Just a file system action again
rm -rf some_directory
```

I assume that you have files which have been committed only stored in `working_directory`, if there are also files directly in `some_directory`, you need to `git mv` them too.

Comment: edit: Formatting, but I couldn't edit my previous coomment.This is not working for me. From within project_name I successfully moved .git with `mv software_directory/.git .`  But I don't need any other folders currently in software_directory except for some_directory/working_directory. From within project_name I tried `git mv software_directory/some_directory/working_directory .` but received the error `fatal: source directory is empty, source=software_directory/some_directory/working_directory, destination=working_directory`.

Comment: You need to both `mv` commands on top. Just follow the steps I've shown, if your directory layout is exactly as you showed, it will work. I've tested it. Btw, I encourage you to create a backup!

Comment: This worked when I moved everything from software_dir into project_dir, then moved the working_dir into the project_dir, so thank you. But why did I need to move everything first? Why didn't it work when I tried to only move the working_dir into project_dir?

Comment: Nice to see that it is working for you! I didn't know if there are files which have been committed or not. (You might have simplified the dump shown in the question). That's why I tried to suggest the most reliable way